# JDBC connect to Java database in Azure

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, jdbc

I have a database in Azure and want to connect to it using my java.
I've tried running the sample code:
package com.function;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Function {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Connect to database - all strings were taken
        String hostName = "HOSTNAME";
        String dbName = "DBNAME";
        String user = "MY_USER";
        String password = "MY_PASSWORD";
        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:1433;database=%s;user=%s;password=%s;encrypt=true;"
            + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;", hostName, dbName, user, password);
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String selectSql = "SELECT * FROM BUSINESSES FOR JSON PATH";

            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql)) {
                while (resultSet.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " "
                        + resultSet.getString(2));
                }
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, every time I try to run it I get the error [image]

I'm not sure how to solve it, and if anyone knows what the problem is it would be of great help.

Notice - in the pom.xml there are references to these:

```
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
 <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
 <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to start the application in a console (the screenshot looks like that), so I assume you do something like

```
java Function
```

from the directory where the class file is residing.

When starting it this way, you have to provide the jdbc-driver's jar as classpath:

```
java -cp .;some/dir/where/the/jar/resides/mssql.jar Function
```

The reference in the pom.xml only lead to the download of the jar when using maven but doesn't add it automatically to the JVM's "global" classpath.

If it's 100% sure that the JDBC-driver is part of the classpath, you can try and register the driver to the `DriverManager` yourself (the driver is supposed to do that itself, but some of them don't):

```
DriverManager.registerDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: Yes this would make sense, but I am using maven to execute the file (mvn -q)
And the dependency is added by Maven as far as I understnad.
Furthermore I can access this function through HTTP request where I also get this error :/

Comment: @CmpScienceLearner See my added text